# In asp.net mvc by mistake i set Home => Index set as start page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

by mistake i set `Home => Index` set as start page. but now when i run the project it gives following error

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml

when i remove `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` from url it runs correctly. So every time i have to remove `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` from url.

How to undo that settings???

Comment: You can change default page in your Route Config file.

 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: MVC works by calling controller methods that return views, not by calling the view directly. Suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to understand the basics.

Answer (score 1):

By requesting `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` you are trying to get the content of `Index.cshtml` file which is blocked in `Web.config` in your views folder.

The correct URL for Index action in Home Controller is `Home/Index`

By the way, one of the most common reasons for your issue is when you try to run/debug your project from visual studio and you selected some specific `cshtml` file (In your case, you most probably try tor run the project while you are working on `Index.cshtml` file )

Comment: Thanks for response. I found solution in following way.
Right Click on project name => Project properties => Web => Specific Page =>removed this path /Views/Home/Index.cshtml and left it blank. Problem solved